# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an endpoint for a user to login. it looks to see if a user has a refresh cookie and if not, generates a pair of auth and refresh tokens.

```
async login(_, { email }, { req, res }) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("*** COULDN'T FIND USER WITH EMAIL ", email);
    }

    const tokenAuth = 
      jsonwebtoken.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email }, SECRET_AUTH, { expiresIn: TOKEN_AUTH_EXPIRY });

    const tokenRefresh = 
      jsonwebtoken.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email }, SECRET_REFRESH, { expiresIn: TOKEN_REFRESH_EXPIRY });


    const saveRefreshToken = await Token.create({
      hash: tokenRefresh,
      user_id: user.id,
    })

    const tokens = {
      tokenAuth,
      tokenRefresh
    }

    res.cookie('tokenAuth', tokenAuth, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 300000 })
    res.cookie('tokenRefresh', tokenRefresh, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 2592000000 })
    res.status(200).send({ data: { message: "Tokens Generated!", tokens, login: true }});

  } catch(e) {
    console.log('*** Error on /login:', e)
  }
}
```

But I get the following errors

```js
(node:14905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at apollo_server_core_1.runHttpQuery.then (/Users/z/server/node_modules/apollo-server-express/src/expressApollo.ts:42:17)
(node:14905) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14905) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm only sending back one res, so why's it throwing that error?

Comment: This is all of the error?

Comment: updated with full error

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using `apollo-server-express`? Based on the error message it seems that it is that module that is trying to write headers after they are sent to the client.